# How to show all results in MySQL excluding the ones that are shared by more than one item in a specific row?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I need to show a list of expenses from apartments (units). Some apartments will contribute in all expenses and some only in just a few. I need to separate which contribute in what.

See this fiddle for a full demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d508a/1
From the following query, I only want to see records that DO NOT have multiple linked expense units

```
SELECT idGasto, gastos.idRubro, monto, rubros.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre)
FROM gastos
LEFT JOIN rubros ON gastos.idRubro = rubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tipoUFRubros ON gastos.idRubro = tipoUFRubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tiposUF ON tipoUFRubros.idTipoUF = tiposUF.idTipoUF
GROUP BY gastos.idGasto
```

Results in:

| idGasto | idRubro | monto | nombre | GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1000 | Reparaciones | Departamento |
| 2 | 4 | 100 | Honorarios Administracion | Departamento,Local |
| 3 | 6 | 500 | Reparaciones | Departamento |

I want to exclude the result with `idGasto=2` because it has multiple linked `rubros` records.

### Expected Result

| idGasto | idRubro | monto | nombre | GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1000 | Reparaciones | Departamento |
| 3 | 6 | 500 | Reparaciones | Departamento |

I tried the following, but that only limited the records that were linked and I shouldn't have to specify the specific Ids

```
SELECT idGasto, gastos.idRubro, monto, rubros.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre)
FROM gastos
LEFT JOIN rubros ON gastos.idRubro = rubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tipoUFRubros ON gastos.idRubro = tipoUFRubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tiposUF ON tipoUFRubros.idTipoUF = tiposUF.idTipoUF
WHERE tiposUF.idTipoUF = 1
AND tiposUF.idTipoUF NOT IN (
    SELECT idGasto
    FROM gastos 
    JOIN tipoUFRubros ON gastos.idRubro = tipoUFRubros.idRubro
    JOIN tiposUF ON tiposUF.idTipoUF = tipoUFRubros.idTipoUF
    WHERE tiposUF.idTipoUF = 2
)
GROUP BY gastos.idGasto
```

**Failed Results:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d508a/2

| idGasto | idRubro | monto | nombre | GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1000 | Reparaciones | Departamento |
| 2 | 4 | 100 | Honorarios Administracion | Departamento |
| 3 | 6 | 500 | Reparaciones | Departamento |

---

The following is the schema and setup script:

- **tiposUF**: Type of units that have to pay the expenses
- **rubros**: Type of expenses, that I group into headings
- **tipoUFRubros**:  M:N link between type of units (`tiposUF`) and the headings (`rubros`)
- **gastos**: Expense records

```sql
-- List of type of units that have to pay the expenses
CREATE TABLE tiposUF(
    idTipoUF int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombre varchar(250) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tiposUF` (`nombre`) VALUES
('Departamento'),
('Local');

-- type of expenses
CREATE TABLE rubros(
    idRubro int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombre varchar(250) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `rubros` (`nombre`) VALUES
('Impuestos'),
('2'), -- not important
('3'), -- not important
('Honorarios Administracion'),
('5'), -- not important
('Reparaciones');

-- M:N Link between units and expenses
CREATE TABLE tipoUFRubros(
    idTipoUFRubro int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    idRubro int not null,
    idTipoUF int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO tipoUFRubros (idRubro,idTipoUF) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1),
(2,2),
(3,2),
(4,2);

-- Expenses
CREATE TABLE gastos(
    idGasto int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    idRubro int not null,
    monto int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO gastos (idRubro, monto) VALUES
(6,1000),
(4,100),
(6,500);
```

Comment: Why the -1 vote ???

Comment: Does `HAVING` work in your query to filter the rows after the `GROUP BY` operation?

Comment: downvote most likely because you only provided the schema, this is a _data_ related issue so you also need to provide the insert statements for all of the tables so that we can easily follow along and verify our answers before posting them. If you post the minimal insert statements to reproduce the results we can clean it up for you ;)

Comment: Glad to help, check out the new edit, the key with SQL questions is to ask the specific question first, then at the end or via sqlfiddle.com provide a script to replicate the example environment. Also avoid images, because no one wants to type all that setup script by hand. Doing this work up-front will mean you get answers really quickly, and often you find the answer yourself as part of the journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a grouped result set, we can use the `HAVING` clause to apply filter criteria against an aggregate function on that set. In this case, you only want the results that *Have* a `COUNT` of `tiposUF.nombre` that is less than 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d508a/3

```
SELECT idGasto, gastos.idRubro, monto, rubros.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre)
FROM gastos
LEFT JOIN rubros ON gastos.idRubro = rubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tipoUFRubros ON gastos.idRubro = tipoUFRubros.idRubro
LEFT JOIN tiposUF ON tipoUFRubros.idTipoUF = tiposUF.idTipoUF
GROUP BY gastos.idGasto
HAVING COUNT(tiposUF.nombre) < 2
```

Results:

| idGasto | idRubro | monto | nombre | GROUP_CONCAT(tiposUF.nombre) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1000 | Reparaciones | Departamento |
| 3 | 6 | 500 | Reparaciones | Departamento |

Comment: Many thanks @ChrisSchaller, I've tried `HAVING` after group by, but I didn't do it properly, because it showed no results. Now it does. Thanks!!!

Comment: sorry, my mistake on the less than sign ;)